# Who is user 1013 on a mounted directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount

I have a remote server that I mounted to my local machine and every time I try to save a file it wants authorization in the form of my sudo password.

I think the problem is that the directory looks like this

```
amflare@local:~/mnt/websites$ ll
total 56
drwxrwxr-x 1    1013    1013 4096 Apr  7 16:30 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 amflare amflare 4096 May 10 11:10 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1    1013    1013 4096 Apr 28 12:50 dir1/
drwxr-xr-x 1    1013    1013 4096 May 10 13:15 .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1    1013    1013  852 Feb 14 16:54 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1    1013    1013   37 Feb 14 16:54 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x 1    1013    1013 4096 Apr 28 12:50 HTPASSWD/
drwxr-xr-x 1    1013    1013 4096 Feb 14 16:54 lib/
drwx------ 1    1013    1013 4096 Feb 16 15:57 .Trash-1000/
drwxr-xr-x 1    1013    1013 4096 Feb 14 16:54 dir2/
drwxr-xr-x 1    1013    1013 4096 Feb 14 16:54 dir3/
drwxr-xr-x 1    1013    1013 4096 May  1 15:24 dir4/
```

On the server, it has the proper owners though, and if I try to run `chown` on the mounted directory locally, it just says, `chown: cannot access './dir1': Permission denied`.

Who is this mystery user, and how can I fix it so that I don't have to authorize every save attempt?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though your server has a user with the gid/uid of 1013 and your client machine does not. If you `cat /etc/passwd |grep 1013` on the server, you should be able to see which user has that uid/gid.  Take a look at this thread for more info on solving the id mapping:

https://serverfault.com/questions/514118/mapping-uid-and-gid-of-local-user-to-the-mounted-nfs-share

Answer (score 0):

**How can I fix it so that I don't have to authorize every save attempt?**

Use `-o idmap=user`.

Ex. `sshfs -o idmap=user sessy@mycomputer:/home/sessy /mnt/sessy -C -p 9876`

[SSHFS Docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#Options)